# Multiple connections to MySQL Server from same device with EntityFramework: Timeout

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Ive a c# application (A) that continously (once in a second) creates an entry in a database via entity framework on a mysql server on the same computer.

Ive got a asp.net webapplication (B) that pulls some data from the database when I command it to.

If I run A first and then run B, most of the times in a page refresh (where the data is pulled) the via entity framework executed query times out.

Once I stop application A, Application B runs undoubtly fast.

Is there anything to consider when connecting to a mysql server with multiple applications from the same device?

Comment: What is the DB engine of the table/s ? How big is the DB? What type of connection are you using for the mysql - persistant or no?

Comment: Ive installed a MySQL Server as it comes from the installer. I have no idea what the DB engine is. Ive read something of "innodb" in the config files. The DB is 12 mb big. The connection im using? Im creating a datacontext with entity framework each time I save data to the db and when its pulled also. I dont know how entity framework manages this internally but I would guess its not persistant.